# How do I remove emojis from an excel sheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that contains emojis, e.g., , and I am looking for a solution to use Excel VBA to replace the emojis with null.

Emojis can be removed using the Excel replace action, so I recorded a macro to automate the replace.  I opened the recorded macro and it was displayed as follows:

```
Sub Remove_Emojis()

    Cells.Replace What:="??", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

The problem is that VBA doesn't recognize emojis () and replaces them with "??", i.e., Unicode characters above a certain value are not recognized by VBA.

I tried replacing "??" with `ChrW()`:

```
Sub Remove_Emojis()

    Cells.Replace What:=ChrW(128515), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

but this results in an error:

> Invalid procedure call of argument

because the ChrW() function does not allow a value above 65535.  Note: The ChrW() function works if the value of the argument is within the range -32,767 to 65,535.

I expect that there should be support for doing this in VBA given that it can be done in Excel.

Answer (score 9):

I did as small experiment, putting your smiley into excel and let the following code run:

```
Dim s
s = ActiveCell
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Len(s)
    Dim c
    c = Mid(s, i, 1)
    Debug.Print i, c, AscW(c)
Next i
```

My result was

```
 1            ?             -10179 
 2            ?             -8701
```

So obviously, the single character is split into 2 inside VBA. `AscW` and it's pendant `ChrW` deal with 16bit, and the emoji is a 32bit char, so in VBA this emoji character is handled as if there are 2 characters in the string

I added the following code and voilà, the smiley char was gone:

```
Dim x
x = ChrW(-10179) & ChrW(-8701)

s = Replace(s, x, "(smiley)")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = s
```

Probably you have to experiment with the different emojis you are facing and build a list in your replacing routine.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to FunThomas for pointing out that emojis are represented as 2 characters in VBA.  The revised VBA code that works based on this:

```
Sub Remove_Emojis()

    Cells.Replace What:=ChrW(-10197) & ChrW(-8701), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

In my actual solution, I put this into a loop to remove all of the different emojis.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to add this information.