# VBA cannot put certain unicode into Excel properly

Tags: excel, vba, char

I would like to put some special symbol into my worksheet, for example chrw(6161).

```
Public Function testing()
    Selection.value = ChrW(6161)
    Debug.Print AscW(Selection.value) 'Return 49, not 6161
End Function
```

I found that excel would auto switch certain character codes into 0-9, as shown below:
Arabic digits Chrw(1632 to 1641)

```
Chrw(1776 To 1785)

Chrw(2406 To 2415)

BENGALI DIGIT Chrw(2534 To 2543)

GURMUKHI DIGIT Chrw(2662 to 2671)

GUJARATI DIGIT Chrw(2790 To 2799)

Chrw(2918 To 2927)

TAMIL DIGIT Chrw(3046 To 3055)

Chrw(3174 To 3183)

KANNADA DIGIT Chrw(3302 To 3311)

MALAYALAM DIGIT Chrw(3430 To 3439)

Chrw(3664 To 3673)

Chrw(3792 To 3801)

Chrw(3872 To 3881)

MYANMAR DIGIT Chrw(4160 To 4169)

ETHIOPIC DIGIT Chrw(4969 To 4977)

KHMER DIGIT Chrw(6112 To 6121)

MONGOLIAN DIGIT Chrw(6160 To 6169)
```

My question is how I can make this line of code to work. `Selection.value = Chrw(6161)`

Thank you.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378049/14608750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing the post advised by Toddleson, the following code worked properly.

```
Public Function testing()
    Selection.value = "'" & ChrW(6161)
    Debug.Print AscW(Selection.value) 'Return 49, not 6161
End Function
~~
```