# Symbol in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, symbols

If you could help me with this i would be grateful..

Does VBA use only, when using ChrW, decimal code for symbols?
I would love to have "Ϭ" writen in a cell. But all i could find was ChrW(963) which shows "σ" in the end. The symbol "Ϭ" can be found in the hexadecimal code. Insert - Symbol - etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code of a symbol with the `AscW`- function. Insert the symbol into a cell, change to the VBA editor and enter the following command into the immediate window:

```
? AscW(activeCell)
```

The result is the code you use as parameter to `ChrW` - in your case it's 1004.

Note that this is true only if the symbol is part of the 16 bit Unicode set. If you want to deal with symbols that are not within this set (e.g. Emojis), it's getting a lit bit tricky, see [How do I remove emojis from an excel sheet using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55418398/7599798)

Comment: I found out that this works perfectly. Just need to know the hex symbol code.
ChrW("&h03EC")
Thank you!